# PySpark failing to decode 'cp1047' when processing mainframe input

Tags: pyspark, encoding, mainframe, codepages, ebcdic

In one of my requirements is to decode a byte-array based on a `cp1047` code page.  A sample of my code is:

```
ebcdic_str = input_bytes.decode('cp1047')
```

The above code using python works correctly but while executing the same operation as part of the PySpark code (by creating an udf wrapping the above code) i am getting the following error:

```
    ebcdic_str = input_bytes.decode('cp1047')
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp1047
```

I have successfully done the same operation in PySpark using the code page `cp037`, but faced other issues using that code page.  Per a suggestion from IBM the code page has been changed to `cp1047`.  Unfortunately the code itself is failing.

Can anybody suggest a reason for the failure?

Comment: Where is this running?  What version of python are you using?  I'm hoping the answer is you're running this on z/OS with the latest python 3.11 that was released a few days ago.  If you aren't running it on platform, you may have problems.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie i am actually running the above snippet in a PySpark code. Once the file gets created i am sending it out to the MF region..

Comment: Can you provide code that recreated the problem ?   A running piece of code will help immensely as well as a hexdump of the byte array that causes the error.   Also, where are you running the code?  On z/OS or on an external system operating on a file transmitted from the mainframe to the place where your program is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was happening because we are not using a PySpark package `ebcdic` in our code. Once that package is imported the issue was resolved.

A side note, since `ebcdic` package is not a widely used package it might not be pre-distributed on all your worker/edge nodes. So you might want to validate the package is available; otherwise you might receive an 'ebcdic module not found' error.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as correct soas to guide people to the correct solution ... glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the **ebcdic** package is in site-packages since the first release of the Python SDK on z/OS.  So you should be able to import it into your code on z/OS from Python 3.8 and later.  As usual, the more current the version of Python, the better.